# WP site using WordFence trying to run php script on a laravel site on the same server

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, laravel, chmod

We have a production server which we occasionally add staged environments to for quick testing. Inside this server there are Drupal sites, Wordpress sites and one instance of a laravel site. When I navigate to the laravel URL, I am greeted with the error message:

> **Message**: chmod(): Operation not permitted
>
> **Location**: /WordPressWebsite/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/vendor/wordfence/wf-waf/src/lib/storage/file.php

Here's the issue, this error says it's happeneing in the wordpress website which has wordfence enabled, but is being shown on the laravel website (white screen with errors)

I have a WP website that we recently enabled [WordFence](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) on, and there seems to be a php script that is running and trying to `chmod` a directory that does not have sufficient permissions and shouldn't, as it's a completely different website in a different directory.

here is my `.htaccess` file for my laravel site recieveing errors from wordpress site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried disabling wordfence and the issue is active. I could change the permissions on the file to resolve the issue, but this deeply concerns me because I don't know why it would show errors from a different site on the one currently being viewed.

I would assume the php file from the WordFence plugin would only run within the website directory it's under. Does not seem to affect any other sites on that server.

Does anyone know what could cause this type of issue? **Why is my laravel site subject to receiving permission based errors from another site that is in a different directory?**

if you need any additional information or code let me know please.

Comment: Not possible @Altef four

Comment: What is not possible?  it was the servers `php.ini` file had a reference to the php file to run, whenever any site on the server was running it would call it, which would break the laravel site as its not wordpress folder structure. Makes sense. It's suppose to be placed in the root of the website not the server, this was a dev here that incorrectly set it up, after some help we were able to determine solution.